# Getting "No module named queue" when installing tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I am using Anaconda and trying to install tensorflow with pip, but I receive the following error and I am not sure what to do next?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xieyangyang/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/home/xieyangyang/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/home/xieyangyang/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/xieyangyang/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .util.queue import LifoQueue
ImportError: No module named queue
```

Comment: Can you run `pip install --upgrade pip` and then try again?

Comment: when I run pip install, it will happen above error

Comment: I know what to do, this error's reason is that pip install is wrong, you can replace the path:/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python2.7/site-packages's pip folder with right pip

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just reinstall `pip` without `pip`?

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ for more info.